# Something wrong with body proportions, image attached

Tags: adobe-photoshop, painting

I hope its right place to ask this question, anyways this is my example of what I try to paint in photoshop with digital pen and i try to understand what wrong in this paint.

Some say - the head is small, other - the legs are long and so on.

But I see something i miss here. Please help,

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the upper part of the body (to be more specific, the torso) is not proportional to the rest of the body. That's what's beet bothering me a little about the image. Also, the arms appear to be a little small.

[image: http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/human-body.jpg]
[image source](http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/human-body.jpg)

The proportions used in figure drawing are:

- An average person, is generally 7-and-a-half heads tall (including the head).
- An ideal figure, used when aiming for an impression of nobility or grace, is drawn at 8 heads tall.
- A heroic figure, used in the heroic for the depiction of gods and superheroes, is eight-and-a-half heads tall. Most of the additional length comes from a bigger chest and longer legs. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_proportions))

Your entire drawing is apx 7 times the height of the head:
[image]

### Ideal body proportions for a woman:

[image: http://www.idrawdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/prop_female.gif] [image source](http://www.idrawdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/prop_female.gif)

Comment: i thought short hands and short torso comes from twisted body position.

Comment: @MaximShoustin not this much, twisting a body doesn't affect the proportions this much, you don't get noticeably shorter when turning. I am also posting an image of some ideal body proportions for a woman right away

Comment: Even though I think this is a great answer and I did upvote it I would also cite where your image came from.  It's solely up to you but in the past we've have people gripe when their pictures are used and note noted.

Comment: @Darth_Vader Thank you for pointing that out to me, I don't usually use other images in my answers so I'm not used to giving sources since there usually aren't any other than myself. I have added image sources now and thank you for upvoting.

Comment: No problem.  Its not required to cite images but in the past we've had issues of the susposed owner.  Either way i think this answers the question.

Comment: While I agree with the diagnosis that the torso isn't realistically proportioned, the part of this answer about "ideal" proportions could use some qualification: "ideal" can vary quite a bit depending on the subject's race, age, body type, etc., as well as the target aesthetic.  I mean, that diagram is pretty obviously for a 20th-century, Western (American, I would guess), probably heterosexual-male-centric concept of Caucasian women.  Which might work for this drawing—but might also be totally wrong for the next.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the breast is extending directly out from the bottom of the neck and this looks a bit un-natural for a woman. As seen in the image provided by Alin, there is a subtle collarbone and upper chest surface area extending from the neck before breasts. Also I think the neck might be just a little too short in your photoshop.

Comment: Agree, thanks, I thought about and if you think the same, its real issue